# Need shorter/more elegant solution to python while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm a new programmer and I was struggling with a solution to this problem:

User Input with Loops and Conditionals. Use  raw_input() to prompt for a number
between 1 and 100. If the input matches criteria, indicate so on the screen and exit.
Otherwise, display an error and re-prompt the user until the correct input is received.

My last attempt finally worked but I'm interested to know your more elegant solutions, my memory appreciates all of your input :P

```
n = int(input("Type a number between 1 and 100 inclusive: "))
if 1 <= n <= 100:
    print("Well done!" + " The number " + str(n) + " satisfies the condition.")
else:
    while (1 <= n <= 100) != True:
        print("Error!")
        n = int(input("Type a number between 1 and 100: "))
    else:
        print ("Thank goodness! I was running out of memory here!")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify the code, using a single loop:

```
while True:
    n = int(input("Type a number between 1 and 100 inclusive: "))
    if 1 <= n <= 100:
        print("Well done!" + " The number " + str(n) + " satisfies the condition.")
        print ("Thank goodness! I was running out of memory here!")
        break # if we are here n was in the range 1-100 
    print("Error!") # if we are here it was not
```

You just print the output and  `break` if the user enters a correct number or `print("Error!")` will be printed and the user will be asked again.

On a side note, if you are using python2, input is the equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`, if you are taking user input you should generally use `raw_input` as per the instructions in your question.